# Create a JNDI Provider Resource in servicebus console using WLST

Tags: chef-infra, weblogic12c, oracle-service-bus

I need to create a **JNDI** provider resource in the **servicebus console** using **WLST** as part of my Chef Automation. I knew the process of manual creation but didn't have the WLST script. I didn't find the necessary information on any blogs or official documents as well. Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can start reading these documentations : [Oracle WebLogic Server 12c: Using the WebLogic Scripting Tool](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/fmw/wls/12c/06-WLST--4474/cmdline.htm), [WebLogic Scripting Tool](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24491/toc.htm) and [WLST Command Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24490/toc.htm)

Please note that the WLS admin console has a record mode. When you create or update your configuration, the console records all your actions in a wlst file. Very usefull to learn WLST.

Comment: Hi Collin, Thanks for the immediate response. I know the process of  recording in weblogic console and fetch the WLST scripts. But I don't know the recording is possible for Servicebus Console. I went through the Oracle's official documentation as well. I didn't find the correct approach to do that. If you knew, could you please point me to where to check or if possible could you please provide me the script. Thanks and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Can you see your JNDI provider in the config.xml file in your domain ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can be a solution for you. Here is example for 11g. 12c is very similar (sorry, I noticed it is about 12c after I wrote whole instruction) and whole idea is the same.

Menu visible after login, with all menu item mentioned below - 11g:
[image]

Here is 12c menu:
[image]

I. Create new resource

1. Login to OSB Console, by default http://localhost:7001/sbconsole
2. On the left side click on System Administration item
3. Then find JNDI Providers, under Global Resources
4. Start new OSB Console session, click Create at the top left corner
5. Click Add
6. Provide all the required details
7. Click Save
8. Activate session - click on green Activate button, in the left top corner

II. Export created resource

1. In the left find and click on System Administration
2. Find and click Export Resources
3. At the top click on Export Resources
4. Click on + button next to first listed item called System
5. Tick the checkboxes next to JNDI Providers which are part of your interest
6. At the bottom click Export
7. Select if you want to protect Sensitive Data (and provide pass-phrase) or not
8. Click Finish Export

Now you have a JAR file which you can play with - extract files, update content of XML files which contain your JNDI Provider definition, add the new ones, re-pack and re-deploy using WLST.

Below is description how to deploy OSB JAR using WLST. There is a chance it requires small changes to handle JNDI Providers deployment.
https://redstack.wordpress.com/2011/08/25/getting-started-with-continuous-integration-for-osb/